# detect if setInterval timer is complete in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I was trying to build a HTML5 snake game using Javascipt. I have one major problem left to be fixed and not able resolve it after hours of thinking.

This is to do with setInterval and snake movement on arrow key press. When the arrow keys are pressed quickly.. almost like multiple key press the game ends (it is meant to end as the snake runs over itself)

Working model with the issue explained: http://jsfiddle.net/MgsZp/29/

Situation: Snake is moving downwards, when I press left and then up arrow quickly the snake runs over itself (moving only up) as the time Interval for left arrow is cleared instantly. Instead it should move left and then up.

I was trying to store the arrow keys pressed in Array for such situations but not able to handle it.

Example:

var arrowArray = [] ; /* stores arrow keys pressed */

// on key press setInterval(move_snake, timer) in direction as stored in arrowArray[0]

// arrowArray.shift() to remove the current direction in which the snake moves and give way for next direction in arrowArray[0]

Now how do I wait until snake has moved in one direction before moving in second direction when arrow keys are pressed quickly. Tried using setInterval inside setTimeout for waiting timer to end but didn't succeed.

HELP?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: instead of the arrow keys clearing the interval and starting it again, you should just have the arrow keys change the direction the snake will go on the next frame. This avoids the little delay I see whenever I change the direction of my snake. The arrow keys should just set the next direction of movement. Then when the interval function runs again, it checks that the next direction is valid. This fixes your problem where the snake tried to go in the opposite direction.

Comment: You were right. By having arrow keys only to change direction and to use setInterval to draw the snake avoids the delay when direction changes. But the original problem still exists when you quickly press keys almost like multi keypress.. i.e, when the snake moves downwards and you click left and up keys almost instantly.. the snake moves back upwards without moving left first.. Hers's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d2uxc/

Answer (score 1):

Try this: in your handler for the key press, do `arrowArray.push(newDirection);` and in each frame, either shift the new direction off or use the current direction. That way the snake can change direction once per frame and if, say, the snake is going down, then the user pressing right, up, right, down before the next frame comes around will result in the right thing happening.

Comment: i tried this, to push new key values and shifting them but the problem remains the same. Suppose the arrowArray has {down} when left and up keys are pressed instantly.. arrowArray = {up} instead of arrowArray = {left, up} as setInterval clears left almost instantly.